# Manifests for Windows 8 Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, manifest

I am examining Microsoft sample app "DirectX 3D shooting game sample". And I can see two manifests: `Package.appxmanifest` and `StoreManifest.xml` in the project.

After that I created a new WP8 project from template named "DirectX App (Windows Phone 8.0)".
The latter one contains `WMAppManifest.xml`.

All these manifests describe different things. E.g. `Package.appxmanifest` describes supported device orientations, meanwhile `WMAppManifest.xml` does not contain such an info.

My question is: what manifest is really needed to make an app for Windows Phone Store? And how do I specify supported device orientations for `WMAppManifest.xml` (because my game project is based on "DirectX App (Windows Phone 8.0)" template).

Answer (score 0):

They are for different things. You can see what's in the application manifest (package.appxmanifest); there's even a designer for it in Visual Studio.

For the Store manifest, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj730526.aspx